# Where/How to Implement a Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, compare

I'm still very new to java and I run into a lot of issues with the organization of code.  I know a class should contain data and methods that operate on that data, but I still find (what seems to me) grey areas as to how code should be organized.

For example, I have Object1 which contains data and methods that operate on the data.  Object1 contains a method that will return(get) an unsorted Map of data that this class derived.  In DifferentObject1 class I use data from Object1 to build out a graph of this data.  DifferentObject1 needs the data in the map it received to be sorted.  The keys in the map are strings, and the values are floats.

My goal is to sort the map from greatest to least according to the value of the float.  As far as organization of code goes, where should the sorting of this data happen?  Right now, the _myData variable is an unsorted Map of data.  Also, is implementing Comparator on a class the best way to sort the map?

Here is some code to help you to visualize:

```
public class Object1
{
   private Map<String, float> _myData = new HashMap<String, float>();

   public Object1
   { 
       *do stuff....*
   }

   public Map<String, float> getMyData() { return _myData; }
}

public class DifferentObject1
{
    public DifferentObject1(Object1 obj1)
    {
        *do stuff with obj1*
    }
}
```

So basically my DifferentObject1 class should display a sorted graph of data after my DifferentObject1 class is done using the data to build the graph.

Comment: What is happening with this place?  I get down votes and don't even know why.

Comment: I didn't down vote you and I don't plan to, but I suspect it's because if you type the words "comparator sort java" into google, [this is the first returned link](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/) I suggest reading that. Also, `Map`s aren't for sorting.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did research, but sometimes I don't always understand what I'm reading and the solutions provided.  That's why I asked the question here.  I was seeking more depth in understanding my issue.

Comment: @durron597: TreeMap is for sorting ;)

Comment: If you don't understand a tutorial, then ask specific questions about what in the tutorial you don't understand. Doing this and showing your attempt will likely get you much better answers and a lot more respect here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't know if you remember being new to programming or not, but it is not always easy trying to convey a question about your confusion on a topic that has you totally confused.  I'll try to do better next time.

Comment: I understand your confusion, and I'm not one who down-voted you, but I'm just passing my experiences here to you. If we see someone showing evidence of having put in a lot of effort to solve their problem, we usually respond very positively to them. This means showing your attempts, *no matter how bad they are*, and giving concrete evidence that you truly have struggled with the tutorials prior to coming here. Most of us have struggled fiercely trying to learn this stuff, and we highly respect others who show that they've done the same.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Your comments make sense.  I'll definitely do this next time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate design is partly a matter of style, but mostly a matter of what makes sense. If the sorting of data is something that is logically tied to the data itself, then it makes sense for the class that represents the data to implement the `Comparable` interface (and, moreover, to represent the data in a way that is always sorted). If the definition of sort order is contextual (which it sounds like in your application), then it makes more sense to define a `Comparator` appropriate to the context.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to my knowledge, Map is not suited to sort the values. TreeMap inserts the elements in order key-wise, but if you want to sort the values, you'll have to obtain the collection of values first (values() method) and then sort it as a collection.

Comment: Which class should do the sorting?  The class the that requires sorted data, or the class that obtains the data?

Comment: The one that requires the data (the one that calls getMyData())